Bot Framework Python SDK ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
I am looking for some help implementing AAD authentication in a bot framework project with the Python SDK.
What I have done:

cloned this sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/24.bot-authentication-msgraph
followed this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp

configured a MultiTenant bot resource (bots written in Python do not work with app type UserAssignedMSI and I also could not get it running with SingleTenant) including OAuth connection (tested and working both with AAD and AAD v2):

configured an app registration, including API permissions and redirect URI





I have checked my app reg by calling it directly and it does work flawlessly returning a 200 response and access token:

In VS Code, I have a python 3.11 venv. I successfully start my bot web app and open it in the emulator by also providing the app id and client secret:

However, when the flow starts executing the authentication logic I get this error in the console, essentially telling me something is Unauthorized. At this point I am confused and have no further ideas how to debug this considering my resources and configurations appear to be correctly set. I am working in a client's tenant where I have contributor role and have created all stated resources on my own. Is it still possible an admin needs to authorize something? What am I missing?

 [on_turn_error] unhandled error: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\core\bot_adapter.py", line 174, in run_pipeline
    return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\core\middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\core\middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal  
    return await callback(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\bot\bots\dialog_bot.py", line 31, in on_turn
    await super().on_turn(turn_context)
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\core\activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn
    await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
  File "working_dir\bot\bots\dialog_bot.py", line 38, in on_message_activity
    await DialogHelper.run_dialog(
  File "working_dir\bot\helpers\dialog_helper.py", line 16, in run_dialog
    await dialog_context.begin_dialog(dialog.id)
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\dialog_context.py", line 121, in begin_dialog
    return await dialog.begin_dialog(self, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\component_dialog.py", line 67, in begin_dialog
    turn_result = await self.on_begin_dialog(inner_dc, options)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\bot\dialogs\logout_dialog.py", line 21, in on_begin_dialog
    return await super().on_begin_dialog(inner_dc, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\component_dialog.py", line 221, in on_begin_dialog      
    return await inner_dc.begin_dialog(self.initial_dialog_id, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\dialog_context.py", line 121, in begin_dialog
    return await dialog.begin_dialog(self, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\waterfall_dialog.py", line 64, in begin_dialog
    return await self.run_step(dialog_context, 0, DialogReason.BeginCalled, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\waterfall_dialog.py", line 154, in run_step
    return await self.on_step(step_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\waterfall_dialog.py", line 130, in on_step
    return await self._steps[step_context.index](step_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\bot\dialogs\main_dialog.py", line 51, in prompt_step
    return await step_context.begin_dialog(OAuthPrompt.__name__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\dialog_context.py", line 121, in begin_dialog
    return await dialog.begin_dialog(self, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\prompts\oauth_prompt.py", line 168, in begin_dialog     
    output = await _UserTokenAccess.get_user_token(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\dialogs\_user_token_access.py", line 27, in get_user_token      
    return await user_token_client.get_user_token(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botframework\connector\auth\_user_token_client_impl.py", line 44, in get_user_token
    result = await self._client.user_token.get_token(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "working_dir\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botframework\connector\token_api\aio\operations_async\_user_token_operations_async.py", line 100, in get_token
    raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
botframework.connector.token_api.models._models_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
Datetime with no tzinfo will be considered UTC.


tried logging in from the bot emulator and received an Unauthorized response. This happens before even the log in dialog is displayed.


I think you are using the emulator channel to log in to the authentication in the local environment, which won't work. You should enable 'Bypass ngrok for local addresses' as mentioned in the document (the same document you mentioned in your question), which clearly states how to set up the emulator in the authentication process for testin - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#configure-the-emulator-for-authentication.

Thanks for the suggestion. I applied the configuration which I had indeed overlooked but got the same error. Tried with identical app registration in a different tenant I have access to and the auth flow did work. I have tried comparing my account permissions between the two tenants and have engaged with the tenant admin to see where the problem might be.

if it works ! then If different tenants are using the same graph permissions, whether it's through admin consent or delegated permissions, you should cross-check to ensure that the consent permissions are consistent. If there are any inconsistencies, it's likely that the consent permission is different.

I solved the issue by changing the bot data residency from "Europe" to "Global" and the related redirect URI's. Unclear what was the root cause though.
